# ReactJS - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, dom-events

I am unable to load the contents of my page. Don't know why I am getting this error maybe due to something related to DOM. I don't how to resolve it. Any help would be genuinely appreciated!
The code goes as follows:

```
   import React from 'react'

const Footer = () => {
   const boxContainer = document.querySelector(".boxContainer");

   for (let i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
       const list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 41, 42, 43, 44, 82, 83, 123, 124, 125, 126, 164, 165, 166, 167, 205, 206, 246, 247, 287, 288, 5, 6, 46, 47, 87, 88, 128, 129, 169, 170, 210, 211, 251, 252, 292, 293, 8, 9, 14, 15, 49, 50, 51, 90, 91, 92, 131, 132, 133, 134, 172, 173, 213, 214, 254, 255, 295, 296, 175, 176, 217, 177, 218, 259, 55, 56, 96, 97, 137, 138, 178, 179, 219, 220, 260, 261, 217, 218, 259, 260, 261, 301, 302, 17, 18, 19, 58, 59, 60, 61, 99, 100, 102, 103, 140, 141, 144, 181, 182, 185, 222, 223, 225, 226, 263, 264, 265, 266, 304, 305, 306, 24, 25, 65, 66, 67, 106, 107, 108, 147, 148, 149, 150, 188, 189, 229, 230, 270, 271, 311, 312, 67, 108, 149, 150, 191, 232, 192, 233, 274, 234, 275, 316, 194, 235, 276, 154, 195, 236, 73, 114, 155, 33, 34, 74, 75, 115, 116, 156, 157, 197, 198, 238, 239, 279, 280, 320, 321, 36, 37, 38, 39, 77, 78, 79, 80, 118, 119, 159, 160, 161, 162, 200, 201, 202, 203, 241, 242, 282, 283, 284, 285, 323, 324, 325, 326,
       ];

       const el = document.createElement("div");
       el.classList = list.includes(i) ? "box active" : "box"
       boxContainer.appendChild(el)
   }
   return (
       <div id="footer">
           <div className="logo">LOGO</div>
           <h1 className="quote">Living, learning & levelling up one day at a time.</h1>
           <h2 className="githubTitle">Want to get in touch with me?</h2>
           <div className="githubChart">
               <div className="dates">
                   <span>Jan</span>
                   <span>Feb</span>
                   <span>Mar</span>
                   <span>Apr</span>
                   <span>May</span>
                   <span>Jun</span>
                   <span>Jul</span>
                   <span>Aug</span>
                   <span>Sep</span>
                   <span>Oct</span>
                   <span>Nov</span>
                   <span>Dec</span>
               </div>
               <div className="boxContainer">
                   <div className="box"></div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div className="githubTitle">ON
               <span className="iconLinks">Github</span>
               <span className="iconLinks">LinkedIN</span>
               <span className="iconLinks">Instagram</span>
           </div>
           <div className="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2023 Aaryan Pinto</div>
       </div>
   )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: Why are you manually creating dom nodes? Thats ReactJs' job.

Answer (score 1):

you're importing react but you're not using 99% of it's features..

and first thing you shouldn't do is declaring a const variable in a loop - you don't change the list so you just keep on using re-declaring it and giving it a new value and using new memory for no reason.

another thing is that you're trying to latch on to the tag with 'boxContainer' className - before you even create it, and this is why it's crashing (in the component what first happens is the code that runs inside of in, and later the return function sends back the JSX which translates to HTML)

I fixed your code a bit and I think this should work -

```
import React from 'react'

const Footer = () => {
   const list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 41, 42, 43, 44, 82, 83, 123, 124, 125, 126, 164, 165, 166, 167, 205, 206, 246, 247, 287, 288, 5, 6, 46, 47, 87, 88, 128, 129, 169, 170, 210, 211, 251, 252, 292, 293, 8, 9, 14, 15, 49, 50, 51, 90, 91, 92, 131, 132, 133, 134, 172, 173, 213, 214, 254, 255, 295, 296, 175, 176, 217, 177, 218, 259, 55, 56, 96, 97, 137, 138, 178, 179, 219, 220, 260, 261, 217, 218, 259, 260, 261, 301, 302, 17, 18, 19, 58, 59, 60, 61, 99, 100, 102, 103, 140, 141, 144, 181, 182, 185, 222, 223, 225, 226, 263, 264, 265, 266, 304, 305, 306, 24, 25, 65, 66, 67, 106, 107, 108, 147, 148, 149, 150, 188, 189, 229, 230, 270, 271, 311, 312, 67, 108, 149, 150, 191, 232, 192, 233, 274, 234, 275, 316, 194, 235, 276, 154, 195, 236, 73, 114, 155, 33, 34, 74, 75, 115, 116, 156, 157, 197, 198, 238, 239, 279, 280, 320, 321, 36, 37, 38, 39, 77, 78, 79, 80, 118, 119, 159, 160, 161, 162, 200, 201, 202, 203, 241, 242, 282, 283, 284, 285, 323, 324, 325, 326,
   ];

   const array = new Array(365);

   return (
       <div id="footer">
           <div className="logo">LOGO</div>
           <h1 className="quote">Living, learning & levelling up one day at a time.</h1>
           <h2 className="githubTitle">Want to get in touch with me?</h2>
           <div className="githubChart">
               <div className="dates">
                   <span>Jan</span>
                   <span>Feb</span>
                   <span>Mar</span>
                   <span>Apr</span>
                   <span>May</span>
                   <span>Jun</span>
                   <span>Jul</span>
                   <span>Aug</span>
                   <span>Sep</span>
                   <span>Oct</span>
                   <span>Nov</span>
                   <span>Dec</span>
               </div>
               <div className="boxContainer">
                {array.map((_, index) =>
                    <div className={list.includes(index) ? "box active" : "box"}></div>
                )}
                   <div className="box"></div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div className="githubTitle">ON
               <span className="iconLinks">Github</span>
               <span className="iconLinks">LinkedIN</span>
               <span className="iconLinks">Instagram</span>
           </div>
           <div className="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2023 Aaryan Pinto</div>
       </div>
   )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Actually I am new to React so not that used to its features. And the appendChild error did go by your suggested code but I didn't get the desired output which i wanted. I'll just link an html code below. Can you just just look at its output and convert it to JSX accordingly. Pls

Comment: HTML CODE link-https://codepen.io/Aaryan-02/pen/eYPgEro